Old python program no longer works after updating from Pi3 to Pi4 - reworked question
Attached is my code with edits reflecting what I've tried so far to get it to run. The app is supposed to show a window with real-time readings of two temperature sensors and a Hall-effect flow sensor. Buttons allow setting a desired temp, like a thermostat, and a subroutine turns on and off a circuit for applying external heat. A real-time plot in this app window displays the current temps and flow and the thermostat set temp. Meanwhile, a data logging file is updated. This code was cobbled together from various examples from the web. It worked on my Pi3 before I tried to upgrade both hardware and software.
I use Spyder for my IDE. When run in Spyder, the main window displays, but without any sensor values and the buttons don't work. A beginning plot is generated but not updated. I get the following error:
File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/BrewPi/RPi4breweryControl.py:448
    main()

  File ~/BrewPi/RPi4breweryControl.py:442 in main
    photo = draw(fig, canvas)

  File ~/BrewPi/RPi4breweryControl.py:159 in draw
    tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg.blit(

  File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py:14 in blit
    _backend_tk.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer.buffer_rgba(),

AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_tkphoto'

EDIT: more info. In line 144, if I comment out "photo = draw(fig, canvas)" the program will run, but the plot does not show in the main window. The buttons in the main window work as expected. When I close the main window, the program stops and a plot is generated. When line 144 is not commented out, spyder reports that "local variable photo is assigned to but never used" (and the program sortof hangs when executed and the error messages are generated.) Maybe I need some other way of embedding the plot in the window and having it update in real time? Maybe using "animate"?
Here's the code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan  7 17:40:12 2020

@author: pi
"""
import sys
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pigpio

import board
import busio
import digitalio

import adafruit_max31865

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import tkinter as tk
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# will be adding graph of temperatures and flow
#import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasAgg

FLOW_GPIO = 22

pi = pigpio.pi()  # connect to Pi
if not pi.connected:
    exit()

# FLOW_SENSOR = 22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# GPIO.setup(FLOW_SENSOR, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

# Initialize SPI bus and sensor.
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
# spi = busio.SPI(MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
csm = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)  # Chip select of the MAX31865 board.
csr = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
# sensor = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(spi, cs)
# Note you can optionally provide the thermocouple RTD nominal, the reference
# resistance, and the number of wires for the sensor (2 the default, 3, or 4)
# with keyword args:
mash = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(
    spi, csm, rtd_nominal=100, ref_resistor=423, wires=3)
rims = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(
    spi, csr, rtd_nominal=100, ref_resistor=430, wires=3)

SIZE = (1250, 500)


def printNiceTimeDelta(stime, etime):
    delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds=(etime - stime))
    if (delay.days > 0):
        out = str(delay).replace(" days, ", ":")
    else:
        out = "0:" + str(delay)
    outAr = out.split(':')
    outAr = ["%02d" % (int(float(x))) for x in outAr]
    out = ":".join(outAr)
    return out


def save_element_as_file(element, filename):
    """
    Saves any element as an image file.  Element needs to have an underlyiong Widget available (almost if not all of them do)
    :param element: The element to save
    :param filename: The filename to save to. The extension of the filename determines the format (jpg, png, gif, ?)
    """
    widget = element.Widget
    box = (widget.winfo_rootx(), widget.winfo_rooty(), widget.winfo_rootx(
    ) + widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_rooty() + widget.winfo_height())
    grab = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)
    grab.save(filename)


class MyGlobals:
    axis = None
    secondAxis = None
    t_array = []
    x_array = []
    y_array = []
    y2array = []
    f_array = []
    s_array = []


g_my_globals = MyGlobals()

# ================================================================================
#       Performs *** PING! ***
# ================================================================================


def run_graph():
    # graphs are global so that can be retained across multiple calls to this callback
    global g_my_globals, flowAxis

    # ===================== Store current ping in historical array =====================#
    g_my_globals.x_array.append(len(g_my_globals.x_array))
    g_my_globals.t_array.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    g_my_globals.y_array.append(fahrMash)
    g_my_globals.y2array.append(fahrRIMS)
    g_my_globals.f_array.append(flow)
    g_my_globals.s_array.append(setTemp)
#    x_array = g_my_globals.x_array
    t_array = g_my_globals.t_array
    y_array = g_my_globals.y_array
    y2array = g_my_globals.y2array
    f_array = g_my_globals.f_array
    s_array = g_my_globals.s_array

    # ===================== Call graphinc functions =====================#
    g_my_globals.axis.clear()

    g_my_globals.axis.set_ylim([50, 175])     # clear before graphing
    g_my_globals.axis.grid()
    g_my_globals.axis.plot(t_array, y_array)
    g_my_globals.axis.plot(t_array, y2array)
    g_my_globals.axis.plot(t_array, s_array)
    g_my_globals.axis.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=8)
    for label in g_my_globals.axis.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
        label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

#            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
#            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

#    g_my_globals.axis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
#    g_my_globals.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#    g_my_globals.axis.set_xticklabels(time.struct_time(t_array,'%H:%M:%S'),rotation="vertical")
#    g_my_globals.axis.set_xticklabels(t_array,rotation="vertical")
    g_my_globals.axis.set_ylabel('Temperature (F)', fontsize=10)
    g_my_globals.axis.set_title('Mash RIMS Flow', fontsize=8)
#    g_my_globals.axis.Axis.xaxis
#    g_my_globals.axis.Axis.xaxis.set_major_locator()
    g_my_globals.axis.plot(t_array, f_array)  # graph the ping values
    g_my_globals.axis.legend(['Mash', 'RIMS', 'Set', 'Flow'], loc='upper left')

# ================================================================================
#   Function:   Set graph titles and Axis labels
#       Sets the text for the subplots
#       Have to do this in 2 places... initially when creating and when updating
#       So, putting into a function so don't have to duplicate code
# ================================================================================


def set_chart_labels():
    global g_my_globals

    g_my_globals.axis.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=8)
    g_my_globals.axis.set_ylabel('Temperature (F)', fontsize=8)
    g_my_globals.axis.set_title('Mash RIMS Flow', fontsize=8)
    g_my_globals.axis.legend(['Mash', 'RIMS', 'Set', 'Flow'], loc='best')

#    g_my_globals.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
#    g_my_globals.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator(range(0, 25, 6)))
#    g_my_globals.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))


def draw(fig, canvas):
    # Magic code that draws the figure onto the Canvas Element's canvas
    figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = fig.bbox.bounds
    figure_w, figure_h = int(figure_w), int(figure_h)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=figure_w, height=figure_h)
    canvas.create_image(SIZE[0] / 2, SIZE[1] / 2, image=photo)
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg.blit(
#    tkagg.blit(
        photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer)
#        photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)
    return photo

# ================================================================================
#   Function:   MAIN
# ================================================================================


def main():
    global g_my_globals
    datalogfile = open("/home/pi/BrewPi/datalog.csv", "w")
    datalogfile.write("Time"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d") +
                      ", RIMS, Mash, Flow, SetTemp, ElapsedTime, secon"+"\n")
    datalogfile.close()
    datalogfile = open("/home/pi/BrewPi/datalog.csv", "a")

    global setTemp, setTime, count, start_counter, photo
    setTime = time.time()
    setTemp = 32
    fixMash = 0
    fixRIMs = 0

    pi.set_mode(FLOW_GPIO, pigpio.INPUT)
    pi.set_pull_up_down(FLOW_GPIO, pigpio.PUD_UP)
    callback = pi.callback(FLOW_GPIO)  # default tally callback

    # define the form layout
    dataframe = [
        [sg.Text('Mash (F):', size=(16, 1), font='Courier 14'),
         sg.Text('     ', font='Courier 30', text_color='red', key='mashF'),
         sg.Text('RIMS (F):', size=(16, 1), font='Courier 14'),
         sg.Text('     ', font='Courier 30', text_color='red', key='rimsF'),
         sg.Text('Set (F):', size=(16, 1), font='Courier 14'),
         sg.Text('     ', font='Courier 30', text_color='red', key='setF'),
         sg.Text('Flow L/hr:', size=(16, 1), font='Courier 14'),
         sg.Text('     ', font='Courier 30', text_color='red', key='flowRate')]
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.Canvas(size=SIZE, background_color='white', key='canvas')],
        [sg.Frame('Mash/RIMS/Flow', layout=dataframe,
                  font='Any 20', title_color='blue')],
        [sg.Button('fix Mash', size=(8, 2), font='Any 16'),
         sg.Button('fix RIMs', size=(8, 2), font='Any 16'),
         sg.Button('Set Temp', size=(8, 2), font='Any 16'),
         sg.Button('Reset Time', size=(8, 2), font='Any 16'), sg.Text(
             '     ', size=(10, 1), font='Any 36', key='setTime'),
         sg.Button('Exit', size=(8, 2), font='Any 16')]
    ]

    # create the form and show it without the plot
    window = sg.Window('Graph', layout, background_color='white', size=(1000,681),
                       grab_anywhere=True, use_default_focus=False, location=(0, 0)).Finalize()
    #window.Maximize()
    print(window.size)
    window['setTime'](0)
    canvas_elem = window['canvas']
    canvas = canvas_elem.TKCanvas

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.0, 5), tight_layout={'pad': 0})
    fig.set_tight_layout
    g_my_globals.axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 8
    plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 8
    plt.tight_layout()

    keypad_active = False
    newSetTemp = 0

    while True:
        global fahrMash, fahrRIMS, flow, flowGal, secon
        window['Reset Time'].Widget.config(takefocus=1)
        event, values = window.read(timeout=0)

        callback.reset_tally()
        time.sleep(2)
        flow = callback.tally()*2.1

        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(27)
            callback.cancel()  # cancel callback
            pi.stop()  # disconnect from Pi
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(21)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(22)
            GPIO.cleanup()
            save_element_as_file(canvas_elem, '/home/pi/BrewPi/plot.png')
            window.close()
            del window
            datalogfile.close()
            sys.exit
            break

        if not keypad_active and event == 'Set Temp':
            keypad_active = True

            keypad_layout = [
                [sg.Input('', size=(20, 3), key='input')],
                [sg.Button('1', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('2', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '3', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('4', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('5', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('6', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '7', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('8', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('9', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('0', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    'Enter', font='Helvetica 12', key='Submit'), sg.Button('Clear', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Text('', size=(20, 3), font='Helvetica 24',
                         text_color='red', key='out')],
            ]

            keypad = sg.Window('Keypad', keypad_layout,
                               default_button_element_size=(20, 10),
                               auto_size_buttons=False,
                               grab_anywhere=False)

            # Loop forever reading the form's values, updating the Input field
            keys_entered = ''
            while True:
                event, values = keypad.read()  # read the form
                if event is None:  # if the X button clicked, just exit
                    break
                if event == 'Clear':  # clear keys if clear button
                    keys_entered = ''
                elif event in '1234567890':
                    # get what's been entered so far
                    keys_entered = values['input']
                    keys_entered += event  # add the new digit
                elif event == 'Submit':
                    keys_entered = values['input']
     #               window_elem.update(keys_entered)# output the final string
                    window['setF'].update(keys_entered)
                    break
                # change the form to reflect current key string
                keypad['input'].update(keys_entered)
            setTemp = float(keys_entered)
            setTime = time.time()
            newSetTemp = 1
            keypad.close()
            keypad_active = False
            window.un_hide()

        if not keypad_active and event == 'fix Mash':
            keypad_active = True

            keypad_layout = [
                [sg.Input('', size=(20, 3), key='input')],
                [sg.Button('1', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('2', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '3', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('4', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('5', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('6', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '7', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('8', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('9', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('0', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    'Enter', font='Helvetica 12', key='Submit'), sg.Button('Clear', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Text('', size=(20, 3), font='Helvetica 24',
                         text_color='red', key='out')],
            ]

            keypad = sg.Window('Keypad', keypad_layout,
                               default_button_element_size=(20, 10),
                               auto_size_buttons=False,
                               grab_anywhere=False)

            # Loop forever reading the form's values, updating the Input field
            keys_entered = ''
            while True:
                event, values = keypad.read()  # read the form
                if event is None:  # if the X button clicked, just exit
                    break
                if event == 'Clear':  # clear keys if clear button
                    keys_entered = ''
                elif event in '1234567890':
                    # get what's been entered so far
                    keys_entered = values['input']
                    keys_entered += event  # add the new digit
                elif event == 'Submit':
                    keys_entered = values['input']
     #               window_elem.update(keys_entered)# output the final string
                    window['setF'].update(keys_entered)
                    break
                # change the form to reflect current key string
                keypad['input'].update(keys_entered)
            fixMash = keys_entered
            keypad.close()
            keypad_active = False
            window.un_hide()

        if not keypad_active and event == 'fix RIMs':
            keypad_active = True

            keypad_layout = [
                [sg.Input('', size=(20, 3), key='input')],
                [sg.Button('1', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('2', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '3', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('4', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('5', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('6', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    '7', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('8', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Button('9', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button('0', font='Helvetica 12'), sg.Button(
                    'Enter', font='Helvetica 12', key='Submit'), sg.Button('Clear', font='Helvetica 12')],
                [sg.Text('', size=(20, 3), font='Helvetica 24',
                         text_color='red', key='out')],
            ]

            keypad = sg.Window('Keypad', keypad_layout,
                               default_button_element_size=(20, 10),
                               auto_size_buttons=False,
                               grab_anywhere=False)

            # Loop forever reading the form's values, updating the Input field
            keys_entered = ''
            while True:
                event, values = keypad.read()  # read the form
                if event is None:  # if the X button clicked, just exit
                    break
                if event == 'Clear':  # clear keys if clear button
                    keys_entered = ''
                elif event in '1234567890':
                    # get what's been entered so far
                    keys_entered = values['input']
                    keys_entered += event  # add the new digit
                elif event == 'Submit':
                    keys_entered = values['input']
     #               window_elem.update(keys_entered)# output the final string
                    window['setF'].update(keys_entered)
                    break
                # change the form to reflect current key string
                keypad['input'].update(keys_entered)
            fixRIMs = keys_entered
            keypad.close()
            keypad_active = False
            window.un_hide()

        if event == 'Reset Time':
            setTime = time.time()

        if event == 'Close':
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(27)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(FLOW_GPIO)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(21)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(22)
            GPIO.cleanup()
            save_element_as_file(canvas_elem, '/home/pi/Raspberry/plot.png')
            window.close()
            del window
            datalogfile.close()
            sys.exit
            break

        # read temperatures
        clcsMash = mash.temperature
        fahrMash = round(9/5*clcsMash + 32 + float(fixMash), 1)
        clcsRIMS = rims.temperature
        fahrRIMS = round(9/5*clcsRIMS + 32 + float(fixRIMs), 1)
        if (fahrMash > (float(setTemp)-1)) and (newSetTemp == 1):
            setTime = time.time()
            newSetTemp = 0
        secon = 0

        # thermostat control
        # was 50, now bigger safety margin
        if (fahrMash < float(setTemp)) and (fahrRIMS < (float(setTemp)+5)) and (flow > 75) and ((fahrRIMS-fahrMash) < 11):
            #        if (True):
            maxSecOn = min(8, flow/15)  # was 12.5 in V1. 13 in V2
            secon = min(maxSecOn, (float(setTemp)-fahrMash)*2)
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(secon)
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)

        run_graph()
        window['mashF'](fahrMash)
        window['rimsF'](fahrRIMS)
        window['flowRate'](flow)
        window['setF'](setTemp)
        window['setTime'](printNiceTimeDelta(setTime, time.time()))
        print("Temperature: {0:0.3f}F".format(fahrMash))
        datalogfile.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") +
                          ","+format(fahrRIMS, '.1f')+","+format(fahrMash, '.1f') +
                          ","+format(flow)+","+format(setTemp) +
                          ","+printNiceTimeDelta(setTime, time.time()) +
                          ","+format(secon)+"\n")


        photo = draw(fig, canvas)
        count = 0
        # window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Not sure what's wrong, but please check the code in the funtion draw !

What version is the matplotlib module in each system?  And what's tkinter's version?

In [3]: matplotlib.version
Out[3]: '3.8.3'
In [4]: import tkinter
In [5]: tkinter.TkVersion
Out[5]: 8.6

Need the 3-digit tkinter version.  Try: print(sg.framework_version)

In [2]: print(sg.framework_version)
8.6.13

Perhaps some useful info. In line 144, if I comment out "photo = draw(fig, canvas)" the program will run, but the plot does not show in the main window. The buttons in the main window work as expected. When I close the main window, the program stops and a plot is generated. When line 144 is not commented out, spyder reports that "local variable photo is assigned to but never used" (and the program sortof hangs when executed.) Maybe I need some other way of embedding the plot in the window and having it update in real time? Maybe using "animate"?
